# Datepicker for Angular 2 version <4

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm trying to incorporate a Datepicker into my Angular app, but everything I've tried to import seems to throw an error with their code when I build with webpack.  Does anyone have any suggestions for an easy to import, simple Datepicker module that works with lower versions of Angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google request will give you some answer. If some results are about angular5+ you can choose an earlier version of that package. Normally, component for angular follow the same version than Angular to help you know which version of the component to use with a specific angular version. You can look on previous version from npm (tab "version") or directly by choosing a tag from the repo (e.g. github).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng/v/2.0.0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datepicker

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material/v/2.0.0-beta.12 (warning beta only for v2)

Answer (score 0):

Full steps provided.
Use this date picker, this has most options made out of date picker.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker